# Can I use an http.ServerResponse as a prototype in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am unable to get this to work:

```
var proxyResponse = function(res) {
  return Object.create(res);
};
```

Calling the standard response methods on the object returned by this method doesn't work, for example:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res = proxyResponse(res);
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

  res.end("Hallelujah! (Praise the Lord)");
}).listen(8080);
```

The server just hangs. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
Object.create(proto [, propertiesObject ])
```

This create a new object which's prototype is proto, the object itself has nothing define on itself:

```
res.foo = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
res.foo();
res = proxyResponse(res);
res.foo();
```

Result:

```
{ socket: 
   { fd: 7,
     type: 'tcp4',
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _readWatcher: 
      { socket: [Circular],
....

{}
```

So why doesn't it throw a error and explodes? Besides the messed up property lookup and setting, there's one reason that it doesn't work.

While your new object references all the same Object as the old one, itself **is NOT** the old one.

At: https://github.com/ry/node/blob/a0159b4b295f69e5653ef96d88de579746dcfdc8/lib/http.js#L589

```
if (this.output.length === 0 && this.connection._outgoing[0] === this) {
```

This finishes the request, `this` is the new object, but `this.connection._outgoing[0]` still references the **old** object, so the request is never finished and the server hangs.

I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve here anyways, since it doesn't make sense to use `Object.create` here, if you're worried about res being overwritten in case of another requests, that's not the case since each res is it's own variable which references a different object.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivo. This makes sense, and should have been something I could find with a bit of hunting through the source. I figured that either (a) there was some magic happening with res or (b) there was a lacuna in my knowledge of prototypal inheritance. As I suspected, the latter is the case.

What I was trying to accomplish was a Proxy design pattern, where I could redefine just one function on the new object, say writeHead, apply some "filter" to it, and call the old res.writeHead at the end. It looks like there's a more simple way to accomplish this, though.